# Remove objects with field null inside an object of objects

Tags: javascript, object

i have this object of objects:

```
fact: {
      brand: {
          old: ['CHERY'],
          new: ['CHERY','FORD']
      },
      year: {
          old: 2019,
          new: 2019,
      },
      km: {
          old: 90000,
          new: 90000,
      },
      model: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      },
      version: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      },
      color: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      }
},
```

I need to somehow iterate on that object and remove the objects containing fields with null values,so the output will be:

```
fact: {
      brand: {
          old: ['CHERY'],
          new: ['CHERY','FORD']
      },
      year: {
          old: 2019,
          new: 2019,
      },
      km: {
          old: 90000,
          new: 90000,
      }
},
```

I know that if it were an array the process would be simpler with the map function, but with an object of objects I don't know if there is a function that helps in this specific case.

Comment: You can still iterate over an object's keys; what's the specific issue? (There are also libraries that abstract that away.)

Answer (score 0):

if it's fine to mutate the existing object and the schema is always like in the example, you can use this:

```
for(let key in fact) {
  if(fact.hasOwnProperty(key) && Object.values(fact[key]).some(v => v === null)) {
    delete fact[key]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the object and then check if any of the values contains `null`, for example:

```js
const data = {
  brand: {
    old: ['CHERY'],
    new: ['CHERY', 'FORD']
  },
  year: {
    old: 2019,
    new: 2019,
  },
  km: {
    old: 90000,
    new: 90000,
  },
  model: {
    old: null,
    new: null
  },
  version: {
    old: null,
    new: null
  },
  color: {
    old: null,
    new: null
  }
};

const containsNull = obj => {
  const values = Object.values(obj);
  return values.includes(null);
}

const parsedData = {};
for (const [key, obj] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (!containsNull(obj)) parsedData[key] = obj
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parsedData))
```

```
>>> {"brand":{"old":["CHERY"],"new":["CHERY","FORD"]},"year":{"old":2019,"new":2019},"km":{"old":90000,"new":90000}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the object keys and for each property use The Object.values() method which returns an array of the given object. For that array, we can use the some function which return a boolean if the condition is true. (I added !val in case you're looking for any falsy value like undefined etc., in case that's not the case, you can just change it to val === null)

Then, just use delete operator which removes a property from an object.

```js
    let fact = {
      brand: {
          old: ['CHERY'],
          new: ['CHERY','FORD']
      },
      year: {
          old: 2019,
          new: 2019,
      },
      km: {
          old: 90000,
          new: 90000,
      },
      model: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      },
      version: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      },
      color: {
          old: null,
          new: null
      }
    };

    const cleanNulls = (obj) => {
       for (var prop in obj) {
          if (Object.values(obj[prop]).some(val => !val)) {
            delete obj[prop];
          }
       }
    }

    cleanNulls(fact);
    console.log(fact);
```